# How to enable auto rotation with adb commands on Android 10 emulators?

Tags: android, rotation, adb

How to enable auto rotation on Android 10 emulators using `adb` commands?

For a testing purpose, I need to rotation my emulators. But every time when I rotate screen, I need to press a little "rotation" button near the bottom of the screen. Otherwise, nothing happens after rotation.

[image]

How can I enable auto rotation using `adb` commands? I have tried the [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/206507/how-to-autorotate-in-lineageos-with-adb) here but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

`adb shell settings put system accelerometer_rotation 1`